# Electrical sounds in earphones when laptop is plugged in

Tags: 12.04, sound

I hear annoying electrical static noises in my earphones when my laptop is plugged in. They disappear upon my unplugging the power supply. However there is still a buzz when I move the cursor. Can this problem be fixed?

My Ubuntu version is 12.04. The laptop is a Dell Latitude D630.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be a number of things, but does the noise change if you move the wire to the wall socket or to the power in socket on your computer? If so it could be a faulty plug, wall socket or input socket.  If you leave the power turned on, but remove the power cable from the Computer, does it stop? If not then theproblem is with the power converter suppression unit.

Comment: If the input cord from my speakers gets too close to the USB dongle to an old wireless keyboard/mouse, it makes whines, pops and clicks. Move wires and cables around. Move your wireless mouse dongle to a USB port on the other side of the computer from the earphone/speaker jack.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably related to improper electrical isolation, or due to power supply noise.

Noise on the power supply could possibly be transferred over to the headphones. The issue is caused by improper electrical shielding or isolation. There is generally no fix for this because it is in the hardware design. You could listen to it while unplugged.

An alternative solution, assuming that you have some familiarity with electronics, is to build a static limiter.
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/Diode%20Limiters.pdf

By adding a capacitor in series with the headphones and connecting two reverse-parallel diodes across the two terminals, it will reduce the amount of pops, clicks, and static.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved by my switching power adapters. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I switched power adapters and the problem seemed to go away.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs in two cases

1.) When electrical supply is more than your laptop's charger standards

```
                 or
```

2.) When electrical supply is less than your laptop's charger standards
Your problem will be fixed when power supply to your house or workplace is
treated.

Try listening to the earphones while your laptop is plugged in at another place different from you electricity supply.

I've a DELL inspiron 1545 and... this problem occured many times with it..... and cured automatically

Answer (score -1):

[FIXED] This problem is so rare that the dell folks did't belived me and said that they never noted or encountered such an issue before,no diagnostic worked...and finally after two three days of searching I found a fix,not sure if it will work for others but it worked for some and me.Solution is Extension Cord/Electrical Flex Box,please note that I am not talking about any power strips or surge protectors by belkin etc..i have a cheap power strip with a short wire of 5 feet and that didn't worked..I am talking about an Extension Cord/Electrical Flex Box with a very long cable tied circularly inside a plastic casing, don't worry there are many on amazon,they look like this :-

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51w9YSgj%2BoL.*SY355*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51w9YSgj%2BoL._SY355_.jpg)

test your luck and see if it helps..cheers :p

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and include that link at a sensible place? Thanks. :-)